# Automate Copying new Access Token

Tags: powershell, thunderclient

I'm using Thunder Client in VSCode to help with a PowerShell script that needs to call a Dell API. The access token is stored as follows:

```
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer <token here>")
```

I need to copy the new Access token whenever it needs to be refreshed (every 60 minutes courtesy of Dell.) Also note that, for whatever reason, the auto refresh does not work in either Thunder Client nor Postman.

Is there any way to automate copying this string to insert into my script? I'd prefer not to have to add a manual step to what is supposed to be a fully automated script.

I'm digging through the documentation to see if there's any kind of way to interact with Thunder Client via PowerShell, but I don't see any. I fear I may need to rewrite the script I have using something besides PowerShell, but before I undertake that, I figure I'll ask to see if I'm missing something.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.